# How to convert jUnit test case written using Mockito into EasyMock

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, easymock

I have written test cases using Mockito and Powermockito, but now I have to write them by using EasyMock in place of Mockito. I have tried to do so but no success.
Test case using Mockito :

```
public class FTPUtilsTest {

     FTPUtils ftpUtils ;
    FTPClient ftpClient =Mockito.mock(FTPClient.class);
    @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
            PowerMockito.whenNew(FTPClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(ftpClient);      
            ftpUtils = new FTPUtils("ace.dev.demo","user1","user1",21);
            Mockito.when(ftpClient.isConnected()).thenReturn(true);

        }
    @Test
        public void testRemoveDirectory() throws FileAgentException, IOException{

            String dirName="removeDir";
            Mockito.when(ftpClient.removeDirectory(dirName)).thenReturn(true);
            assertTrue(ftpUtils.removeDirectory(dirName));      
        }
}
```

How can I replace `Mockito.when(ftpClient.removeDirectory(dirName)).thenReturn(true);`
using EasyMock

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
expect(ftpClient.removeDirectory(dirName)).andReturn(true);
```